# Fastest way of finding whether entire table column is empty using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a very big gridview. Each column has a class name associated with it. What is the fastest way of finding and hiding the column, if the entire column is empty? The empty column contains `&nbsp;`. I tried this, but it does not work for me:

```
$(".grid_tbl td.SubProject:empty").length;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.filter` and check the length

```
var $column= $(".grid_tbl td.SubProject");
var columnIsEmpty = $column.filter(function(e){
        return e.text() == "$nbsp";
    }).length === $column.length;
```